# DLLs referenced from class library not copied to output directory

Tags: .net-core

I have two .NET Standard libraries, compiled as `Foo.dll` and `Bar.dll`. `Bar` contains a reference to `Foo`. In my solution I have a .NET Standard class library,`MyClassLibrary.csproj`, which contains code that references both DLLs. They are referenced from `MyClassLibrary.csproj` like so:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Foo">
    <HintPath>..\..\lib\Foo.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Bar">
    <HintPath>..\..\lib\Bar.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

`MyClassLibrary.csproj` is in turn referenced from `MyApp.csproj`.

When I build `MyApp`, **both** DLLs are copied to `MyClassLibrary/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0`. However, **only** `Bar.dll` is copied to `MyApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1`, with the result that I get an error at runtime (*Could not load file or assembly 'Foo...'*). If, on the other hand, I remove the one line of code in `MyClassLibrary` that calls into `Bar`, `MyApp` ends up with a reference to `Foo.dll` but **not** `Bar.dll`.

How can I force both DLLs to be copied to the app output directory? I have tried setting `<Private>true</Private>` ("Copy local" in Visual Studio), and setting `CopyToOutputDirectory` on both files, to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries used by your Class library are not automatically brought in if you are referencing them directly on the filesystem. Two options are:

1) Reference Foo and Bar in MyApp

2) Create a Nuget package for MyClassLibrary where you can include or specify the dependencies. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution

**Edit**. Because you are using .NET Standard under Properties->Package you can generate a Nuget package. 
IF you don't want to have to upload it to a feed of some sort you can use Nuget's local feed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds